# jquery-tabledit Not sending identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tabledit

I'm trying to use: https://github.com/markcell/jquery-tabledit/blob/master/README.md, and have it set up so its sending data to the form, unfortunately it currently not including the identifier in the form post, an would be grateful for any help.

I'm using the example on the website:
HTML Code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
<caption>
Click the table cells to edit.
</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Username</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">1</th>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>@mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">2</th>
  <td>Jacob</td>
  <td>Thornton</td>
  <td>@fat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">3</th>
  <td>Larry</td>
  <td>the Bird</td>
  <td>@twitter</td>
</tr>
```

```
$('#example').Tabledit({
            url: 'example.php',
            editButton: false,
            removeButton: false,
            columns: {
                identifier: [0, 'id'],
                editable: [[1, 'First Name'],[2, 'Last Name'],[3,  'Username', '{"1": "@mdo", "2": "@fat", "3": "@twitter"}']]
            }
        });
```

The only data in the post is the field that was edited and the action. Any help getting the identifier into the post would be most grateful. as you can tell new to this.,

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem, but I figured it out. Are you using an older example or from another website? I recognise it from looking for in-line editors, but I can't find it again.

Anyway, you want to change

`<th scope="row">2</th>` to `<td scope="row">2</td>`

Looks like you have to keep `<th>` in the header (where it supposedly belongs)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. You saved my time